# Rewrite Rule in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The URL in my site is https://www.artmail.xyz/single.php?id=37
I want to make it https://www.artmail.xyz/single/37.html

I added the following line in my .htaccess:
RewriteRule ^([^/]*).html$ /single.php?id=$1 [L]

But nothing is happening. No error also.
Is it possible Mod rewrite is 'off' with my server? How can I check. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Certainly it is possible that the rewriting module is not active:

- it is an optional module that needs to be loaded into the server
- you need to enable it for the specific location (check the documentation for the `AllowOverride` directive)
- you need to use the well known RewriteEngine on initially

But more important is that your matching pattern actually matches what you want it to match:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?single/(\d+)\.html$ /single.php?id=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: You told "you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). But where should I keep the rules in server configuration? I am using GOdaddy for hosting/ Where should I write the rules? and will the rule be same? Please help me.

Comment: The rule I posted is robust in the sense that it will work likewise in dynamic and in static configuration files. If you operate a separate vServer you have access to the static configuration, since you actually installed it. If however you are using a shared hosting provider then chances are that you not have any access to the real http server's host configuration, since that is shared between thousands of users. In that case you have no option but to use dynamic configuration files.